# AutoRotate / InterfaceOrientation causing Unbalanced calls warnings

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

There's a lot of questions around AutoRotate in iOS7 and although I've read many of them I'm still not sure how to solve my problem.

I've got a (primary) ViewController which should remain Portrait which launches a View that should auto-rotate to Landscape (left or right) but never to Portrait or UpsideDown.
This works fine, however when I pop back to the ViewController, I get an "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions..." message even though the View visually pops properly.

I've had a lot of problems getting the rotations to work correctly, and I found this on SO:
In my AppDelegate I added:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSUInteger orientations=UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    if(self.window.rootViewController){
        UIViewController *presentedViewController=[[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
        orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    return orientations;
}
```

In my (portrait) ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

And in my (landscape) View:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

I've been able to eliminate the warning by changing the View Controller from UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll, however I do not want this behavior.

How can I keep the Rotation behavior I want when pushing/popping without the run-time warnings?